# Tomcat9 keep running under user tomcat9 even after change in /etc/default/tomcat9 file

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, tomcat9, ubuntu-19.10

I want run tomcat9 with a user different from the default, and searching the web, I found out that I can configure this in the file `/etc/default/tomcat`. In this file, I change the lines with `TOMCAT9-USER` and `TOMCAT9_GROUP` and change to the desired user and group I wish tomcat9 was running under. After that, I stop tomcat, and start again (I've trie restart too), but when I run `ps -ef`, tomcat still is displayed running under user tomcat. What I am doing wrong here? Is there any other file I need modify?

Answer (score 2):

I find the problem. With ubuntu, apparently the file `/etc/default/tomcat9` is not used; I managed to change the configuration I wanted with the command: `systemctl edit --full tomcat9.service`, which edits the file `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat9.service`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using service.bat or service.sh to set the user which the tomcat process need to run as.

Try to follow the below Tomcat 9 documentation

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

[Originally this answer appeared under [How do I run Tomcat 9 as a different user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67636268/11748454), which is a duplicate of this question]

The Tomcat 9 packages based on Debian 10 use SystemD to run. Therefore you need to run:

```sh
sudo systemctl edit tomcat9.service
```

(or create a file named `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat9.service.d/override.conf`) and type:

```
[Service]
User=your_user
Group=your_group
```

in the editor that appears. Check the [systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#User=) manual for more options or see the vendor supplied unit file (`/lib/systemd/system/tomcat9.service`).

When you restart your server, it will use the new settings.