# How do I run Tomcat 9 as a different user?

Tags: tomcat

I want to run Tomcat 9 as a specific utility user (Ubuntu 20.04).

As recently as Tomcat 7, this could be accomplished by setting the `TOMCAT7_USER` and `TOMCAT7_GROUP` parameters in `/etc/default/tomcat7/`.

The file `/etc/default/tomcat9` exists by default, but it did not contain user/group parameters.  I tried adding the parameters `TOMCAT9_USER` / `TOMCAT9_GROUP` and `TOMCAT_USER` / `TOMCAT_GROUP` to it, restarting Tomcat each time, but the Tomcat process continues to be owned by the 'tomcat' user instead of the one I specify in this file.

I can find zero documentation on these parameters for Tomcat 9, so I have to assume that Tomcat 9 no longer recognizes these parameters.  I also find zero documentation on the general problem of running Tomcat 9 as a different user.

How do I run Tomcat 9 as a different user?

Comment: This is much more of an "operating system" question than a Tomcat question. Tomcat itself doesn't ship with anything to manage services, users, etc. for *NIX systems. The Windows service installer/runner understands how to tell its Windows Service what that stuff should be, but it's still handled by the OS itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat9 keep running under user tomcat9 even after change in /etc/default/tomcat9 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61398602/tomcat9-keep-running-under-user-tomcat9-even-after-change-in-etc-default-tomcat)